# LaTex Package PGF Math Error with pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I try to create a table in Latex using the data and the code below. However, Texmaker keep giving me the "! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'fdcexp' as a floating point nu". Can anyone please help me to fix this?

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots,booktabs,filecontents,pdflscape}
    \newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{result3.dat}
    model,modelx
    ,y3
    fdcexp,0.402**
    ,-2.19
    L.gdpper,-0.00472
    ,(-1.63)
    growth,0.138
    ,-0.29
    D.lnhuman,-0.533
    ,(-0.60)
    ligdp,-0.251
    ,(-1.55)
    2002.obs,0
    ,(.)
    2003.obs,0.356
    ,-1.44
    2004.obs,0.262
    ,-1.02
    2005.obs,0.605**
    ,-2.32
    2006.obs,0.707***
    ,-2.6
    2007.obs,1.407***
    ,-4.97
    2008.obs,1.943***
    ,-6.67
    2009.obs,2.187***
    ,-6.77
    2010.obs,2.324***
    ,-6.72
    2011.obs,2.483***
    ,-6.67
    2012.obs,2.817***
    ,-7.31
    2013.obs,3.073***
    ,-8.48
    2014.obs,3.495***
    ,-9.26
    fdcall,
    ,
    fdcave,
    ,
    fdcnet,
    ,
    fdcrev,
    ,
    yr2007,
    ,
    _cons,8.796***
    ,-4.23
    N,259
    r2_o,0.152
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{landscape}
    \centering\small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2.2pt}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep = comma,
    display columns/model/.style={string type,column type={l}},
    display columns/modelx/.style={string type},
    ]{result3.dat}
    \end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I would guess that `0.402**` gives a syntax error as floating point due to the `*`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: In fact, the error is the letter as in the error message below, it says that the "unreadable part was near 'fdcexp'". I am not sure about the word "near" in this message.
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'fdcexp' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'fdcexp'..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use either `display columns/0/.style` or `columns/model/.style`, that means either

```
display columns/<column index>/.style
```

or

```
columns/<column name>/.style
```

Because of the `_` in the cells the column model needs `string replace*={_}{\_},`.

Your table is too long, so I remove some lines for the example. Maybe you have to use `longtable`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}% <- added!
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{result3.dat}
model,modelx
,y3
fdcexp,0.402**
,-2.19
L.gdpper,-0.00472
,(-1.63)
growth,0.138
,-0.29
D.lnhuman,-0.533
,(-0.60)
ligdp,-0.251
,(-1.55)
2002.obs,0
,(.)
2003.obs,0.356
,-1.44
fdcall,
,
fdcave,
,
yr2007,
,
_cons,8.796***
,-4.23
N,259
r2_o,0.152
\end{filecontents}
\begin{landscape}
\centering\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.2pt}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
display columns/0/.style={string type,string replace*={_}{\_},column type={l}},
columns/modelx/.style={string type},
]{result3.dat}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

---

Here is an additional suggestion with your long table using package `longtable` as already suggested above:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}% <- added!
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{result3.dat}
model,modelx
    ,y3
    fdcexp,0.402**
    ,-2.19
    L.gdpper,-0.00472
    ,(-1.63)
    growth,0.138
    ,-0.29
    D.lnhuman,-0.533
    ,(-0.60)
    ligdp,-0.251
    ,(-1.55)
    2002.obs,0
    ,(.)
    2003.obs,0.356
    ,-1.44
    2004.obs,0.262
    ,-1.02
    2005.obs,0.605**
    ,-2.32
    2006.obs,0.707***
    ,-2.6
    2007.obs,1.407***
    ,-4.97
    2008.obs,1.943***
    ,-6.67
    2009.obs,2.187***
    ,-6.77
    2010.obs,2.324***
    ,-6.72
    2011.obs,2.483***
    ,-6.67
    2012.obs,2.817***
    ,-7.31
    2013.obs,3.073***
    ,-8.48
    2014.obs,3.495***
    ,-9.26
    fdcall,
    ,
    fdcave,
    ,
    fdcnet,
    ,
    fdcrev,
    ,
    yr2007,
    ,
    _cons,8.796***
    ,-4.23
    N,259
    r2_o,0.152

\end{filecontents}
\begin{landscape}
\centering\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.2pt}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
every head row/.append style={
  before row={\caption{My Table}\label{tbl:MyTable}\\\toprule},
  after row={
    \midrule\endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\scriptsize Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}}\\
    \midrule
    model&modelx\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{{\scriptsize Continued on next page}}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
  }
},
display columns/0/.style={string type,string replace*={_}{\_},column type={l}},
columns/modelx/.style={string type},
]{result3.dat}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Run several times to get:

[image]

---

And an example with more columns in the data file, but only two in the output:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}% <- added!
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{result8.dat}
model,modela,modelb,modelc,modeld,modele,modelf,modelg
    ,y3,fdcexp,0.402**, ,-2.19,L.gdpper,-0.00472
    ,(-1.63),growth,0.138,,-0.29,D.lnhuman,-0.533
    ,(-0.60),ligdp,-0.251,,(-1.55),2002.obs,0
    ,(.),2003.obs,0.356,,-1.44,2004.obs,0.262
    2005.obs,0.605**,,-2.32,2006.obs,0.707***,,-2.6
    fdcall,,,fdcave,,,fdcnet,
    _cons,8.796***,,-4.23,N,259,r2_o,0.152
\end{filecontents}
\begin{landscape}
\centering\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.2pt}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
columns={model,modela},
display columns/0/.style={string type,string replace*={_}{\_},column type={l}},
columns/modela/.style={string type}
]{result8.dat}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or all columns in the output

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}% <- added!
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{result8.dat}
model,modela,modelb,modelc,modeld,modele,modelf,modelg
    ,y3,fdcexp,0.402**, ,-2.19,L.gdpper,-0.00472
    ,(-1.63),growth,0.138,,-0.29,D.lnhuman,-0.533
    ,(-0.60),ligdp,-0.251,,(-1.55),2002.obs,0
    ,(.),2003.obs,0.356,,-1.44,2004.obs,0.262
    2005.obs,0.605**,,-2.32,2006.obs,0.707***,,-2.6
    fdcall,,,fdcave,,,fdcnet,
    _cons,8.796***,,-4.23,N,259,r2_o,0.152
\end{filecontents}
\begin{landscape}
\centering\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.2pt}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
string type,
display columns/0/.style={string replace*={_}{\_},column type={l}},
display columns/6/.style={string replace*={_}{\_}}
]{result8.dat}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I find the problem only exists when I increase the size of the table. For example, if I add 4 or 5 more columns, the code won't work. But unfortunately, I usually work with large table of results.

Comment: @TUNGBUI I have added an example with 8 columns. Note that you really have to use either `display columns/<column index>/.style` or `columns/<column name>/.style` to change the style for single columns.

Comment: I much appreciate your help. So I observed that only the columns with the character "_" hinder the compilation. Is that true?